# Unable to deploy business network using local Composer Playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am unable to deploy the business network using the local playground. It hangs at "Please Wait: Installing Business Network"...and the browser console log shows the following error -
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

I am able to deploy the network using CLI.

I am at 0.13.0 version.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Are you running locally? If so, what is the output of the `docker ps` command. What OS are you on? Have you checked the version of Docker etc?

Comment: Yes....output of docker ps command is -

Comment: It is working now....I cleaned and reinstalled all the docker images...and also changed the host port to guest port mapping.